# Available options for playing a stream or a remote mp3 file on iOS 4

Tags: audio, ios4, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to make an application for listening to podcasts. Each podcast is an mp3 file, around 50MB in size. After reviewing the [Using Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2) chapter of the Multimedia Programming Guide, I decided to use AVPlayer, as the other options did not seem appropriate. However, the more I work with AVFoundation, the more complicated it seems and I have a feeling that simply streaming an mp3 file should be easier. Plus on the top of this document, there is a note stating:

> Important: This document contains
>   information that used to be in iOS
>   Application Programming Guide. The
>   information in this document has not
>   been updated specifically for iOS 4.0

Does that mean that I have some other options, or that AVFoundation is maybe an overkill for what I need to do? I would really appreciate it if someone could clear things out a bit and let me know if I'm making something wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [a pdf](http://cs491f10.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/19-audio-and-video-v2.pdf) with a nice overview of some possible options from [this course blog](http://cs491f10.wordpress.com/). Together with Julian's suggestion this is all I could find so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should explore Cocos Denshion.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:cookbook

The audio engine comes with cocos2d, and it is just 5 classes you can include with your project.

It's very simple to use, as you can see from the above link. It's basically just a wrapper for some AVFoundation classes.

The only trick will be to stream your mp3, but it looks like you can simply update the Cocos Denshion CDAudioManager to hand a URL to the AVAudioPlayer, as a start. Whether or not that satisfies your streaming requirement, I don't know.

At the very least, it will give you some AVFoundation code to study.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this one. I'm also trying to implement the same thing with MPMoviePlayerController, without any special problem so far!